# stream a pdf to a .net webbrowser object on a winform

Tags: .net, pdf, streaming, browser

I have a webbrowser object on a winform that I would like to use to display a pdf.
The pdf resides on a ftp server.  I have been able to show the pdf by downloading it 
to the disk and pointing the webbrowser object to it (navigate), but I want to stream
it for security reasons.  Has anyone been able to stream a pdf to a webbrowser that is located on a .Net winform?

```
    Dim URI As String = host & targetFilename
    Dim ftp As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)

    ftp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, passWord)
    ftp.KeepAlive = False
    ftp.UseBinary = True
    ftp.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

    Using webResp As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(ftp.GetResponse(), System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
        Using respStream As Stream = webResp.GetResponseStream
            If GetFileExtension(targetFilename) = "PDF" Then
                WebBrowser1.DocumentStream = respStream
                Application.DoEvents()
            End If

            respStream.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using the WebBrowser control; why not have it point to a local html file that includes an embed tag:

```
<embed src="ftp://ftpserver/yourpdf.pdf" />
```

I haven't tested it, but the pdf should be served within the context of the control.

Comment: you can always pass credentials in plaintext, but it is not safe.  the unsafe way to do this would be:    ftp://user:password@ftpserver/yourpdf.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the idea Gurdas!  The security concerns (passing credentials) prevent me from implementing this soln.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [PDF Viewer Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/PDFViewerControl.aspx) rather than a web browser control, as a web browser control will require that the client have a PDF Viewer installed.

This will also allow you to stream a document to it.

Comment: The boss doesn't like the idea of having to distribute more files to get this work.  I will use a PDF Viewer Control if I can't get the webbrowser to work.  Will the PDF Viewer Control work well with streamed data?

Comment: Russ, I agree with you that the PDF Viewer Control would be the most "correct" way to do it.  I just don't want to give up on the webbrowser yet.

Comment: The PDF Viewer control will work with streamed data. It is also open source so there will only be the need of one other file to distribute. This is a much better alternative than getting calls from angry people who don't have Acrobat installed because their pdf viewer is showing a big red X

Comment: I agree Russ.  Thanks for helping me with this problem!  I will have to put this project on hold until I can distribute the needed dependency.