# .NET Web Browser Control using in memory data

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, browser, memorystream

I have some binary data in memory (which represents a PDF file).  What I’d like to be able to do is to point the standard .NET browser control directly to this data.  For example:

```
myLib mylib = new myLib();
object vbyt = mylib.GetPDFDocument();
webBrowser1.data = vbyt;
```

Is this possible, or do I need to save the PDF to a file and read from there?

EDIT:

I believe that the following should do what I need, but it just spits out garbage - can anyone tell me why / a way to get this to work?

```
byte[] vbyt = (byte[])mylib.GetPDFDocument();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

ms.Write(vbyt, 0, vbyt.Length);
ms.Position = 0;

//conetent type = "application/pdf";            
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = ms;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why setting `DocumentStream` produces garbage is discussed in this forum post: [Can I pass binary data of a file to WebBrowser control?](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3499063/Can-I-pass-binary-data-of-a-file-to-WebBrowser-con.aspx)

A possible solution is to save the file locally and serve it via html file: [stream a pdf to a .net webbrowser object on a winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610225/stream-a-pdf-to-a-net-webbrowser-object-on-a-winform)

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's a bit more too it than that, [this page should help](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspxProtocol.aspx).

There is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290035/how-do-i-get-a-c-webbrowser-control-to-show-jpeg-files-raw) here.

Comment: FYI it is much easier to save it to a file and just browser.Navigate() to the PDF on disk.

Comment: Just found that answer and was reading up on it, you beat me! Yes saving the page is easier, but the OP seems to want to avoid doing that.

Comment: Agreed - that's why I posted a link explaining how to do it. But it is definitely much more involved than simply Navigating to the PDF.

Comment: Sorry, I think I must have misread 'FYI' as 'IMO' there... Ignore me!