# Create PDF based on the byte field in the Database

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, pdf

I want to view a PDF in a windows form. The PDF data is stored in a database as bytes. I know about web browser controls but don't know how to use it to view a PDF.

I don't want to save the PDF, I just want to view the data.

I read these questions, but they are not descriptive enough and have broken links.
[stream a pdf to a .net webbrowser object on a winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610225/stream-a-pdf-to-a-net-webbrowser-object-on-a-winform)
and 
[Displaying pdf files in a web page from a sql database directly without needing to save them to the server file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747796/displaying-pdf-files-in-a-web-page-from-a-sql-database-directly-without-needing)

Guide me with any links or how to start with it.

Comment: Does your project have a budget? I just dropped a Telerik RadPdfViewer on a winform and in 3 lines of code I was looking at a pdf from a MemoryStream. Other vendors will have similar offerings.